# My elementary OS can't detect my wifi at all, just connect about ethernet. What to do?

Tags: release-loki, wifi, internet, ethernet

It doesn't detect the ability of my laptop to connect to wifi at all. About ethernet it can connect to the internet.

I use a hp15 laptop in dualboot with windows 8.1, which always could connect to wifi. My wifi-adapter is a broadcom BCM43142 802.11 bgn wifi-adapter. I use the newest release, loki 0.4.1. When I use a command to check all the network devices, it just shows me my bluetooth adapter, not my wifi-adapter.

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: When the os was being installed, did you checked the box that offers you to install third-party proprietary software like Flash, mp3 support, drivers, etc? If you did, were you connected by ethernet at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a working Internet connection via Ethernet, run this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot.

If the problem persists, research [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: This download completely fixed my MacBookPro's lack of wireless networking. Why was it necessary to spend an hour or two hunting around the web for this fix. The pieces and parts that comprise this download should be an integral part of the Elementary OS install on any Apple equipment. In the same vein, there is no good reason that setting up networked printers requires having to downloads cups software and then know enough how to access it from a web browser. Both of these problems remind me of the bad old days with AT&T Unix 50 years ago when nothing worked without hours of manual tweaking o

Comment: I don't know about cups, but broadcom's drivers are proprietary and given the nature of this distribution, and licensing factor, it's not supplied out of the box. Some distributions with EULA do that though

Comment: sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source worked perfectly on a HP laptop, thank you :)